# Speed accessing a std::vector by iterator vs by operator[]/index?

Tags: c++, stl, vector, iterator, performance

Say, I have a

```
std::vector<SomeClass *> v;
```

in my code and I need to access its elements very often in the program, looping them forward and backward .

Which is the fastest access type between those two ?

Iterator access:

```
std::vector<SomeClass *> v;
std::vector<SomeClass *>::iterator i;
std::vector<SomeClass *>::reverse_iterator j;

// i loops forward, j loops backward
for( i = v.begin(), j = v.rbegin(); i != v.end() && j != v.rend(); i++, j++ ){
    // some operations on v items
}
```

Subscript access (by index)

```
std::vector<SomeClass *> v;
unsigned int i, j, size = v.size();

// i loops forward, j loops backward
for( i = 0, j = size - 1; i < size && j >= 0; i++, j-- ){
    // some operations on v items
}
```

And, does const_iterator offer a faster way to access vector elements in case I do not have to modify them?

Comment: What did the profiler results show you?

Comment: If i had time and will to profile the code i wouldn't asked here.
I'm just wondering if the stl iterator implementations have some sort of access optimization .

Comment: Consider using `boost::ptr_vector` if the vector owns the objects. Otherwise use `boost::reference_wrapper`.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y Is 'boost::ptr_vector' (in my case) faster than std::vector ?

Comment: Asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at

Comment: @Simone: It's safer and easier. You don't have to worry about looping through the vector, regardless of how it's being destructed. (Exceptions, for example.)

Comment: If speed is really important, you shouldn't store a pointer to SomeClass, but SomeClass itself. This should boost your performance a lot because you'll eliminate all the cache misses. Other than that, in C++11/14, `for(auto&& e : v)` would most likely be the fastest because the compiler can optimise best.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's faster, iterating an STL vector with vector::iterator or with at()?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/776624/whats-faster-iterating-an-stl-vector-with-vectoriterator-or-with-at)

Comment: @Ela782 I really doubt the range-`for` syntax makes any difference to the generated code, since it is defined precisely as equivalent to a manually written loop using iterators (albeit done right, with a cached `end` and preincrement).

Comment: @underscore_d You're correct, the compiler generates the iterator code for the range-for loop.

Comment: I really wish SO has an option to request for removal of answers.  I have the same question.  The code I am working with is high performance server side where squeezing a couple % can mean $.  It would save me a lot of time if someone's done this benchmark.  There are 11 answers.  Almost all of them are utterly useless noise that I have to wade through.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The performance difference is likely negligable or none (the compiler might optimise them to be identical); you should worry about other things, like whether your program is correct (a slow but correct program is better than a fast and incorrect program).  There are other advantages to using iterators though, such as being able to change the underlying container to one with no `operator[]` without modifying your loops.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515527/use-of-iterators-over-array-indices) for more.

const_iterators will most likely have none, or negligable, performance difference compared to ordinary iterators.  They are designed to improve the correctness of your program by preventing modifying things that shouldn't be modified, not for performance.  The same goes for the `const` keyword in general.

In short, optimisation should not be a concern of yours until two things have happened: 1) you have noticed it runs *too slowly* and 2) *you have profiled the bottlenecks*.  For 1), if it ran ten times slower than it could, but is only ever run once and takes 0.1ms, who cares?  For 2), make sure it's definitely the bottleneck, otherwise optimising it will have nearly *no measurable effect* on performance!

Comment: I disagree.  If using indices instead of iterators is going to give you a performance boost, just use integer indices.  You're not losing anything by using indices, and in my opinion it actually looks cleaner (`for( vector<Object>::iterator iter = list.begin() ;` vs `for( int i = 0 ;` )

Comment: @bobobobo - but you also lose the ability to swap container easily, like I mentioned - you can't use a std::list with an integer index.

Comment: @AshleysBrain hints at a good point; _the code you write is not the code that is run_. Often times the compiler can do loop optimizations. So the question of iterator vs index probably does not matter since both will generate very similar assembly code anyways.

Comment: i did a simple loop profiling and found iterator is twice slower in my case and it adds up too fast with overall very slow performance. for parsing i do not recommend using iterators however safe they may look

Comment: It seems inappropriate to respond to a question like this with "you shouldn't care" without any knowledge of the circumstances.

Comment: agree with Hunter's sentiment.  Doesn't answer the question, and instead gave a snooty "here's how you should do it".

Comment: I also agree with Hunters comment. This is a largely inappropriate way to offer help and honestly just looks like discouragement from trying to solve a problem.

Answer (score 27):

A simple loop-based benchmark has been fulfilled. I used VS 2010 SP1 (release configuration).

1. Use iterators (*it = *it + 1;)
2. Use indices (vs[i] = vs[i] + 1;)

In several billions of iterations the second approach turned out to be a bit faster, by 1%. The result *(indices are slightly faster than iterators)* is reproducible but the difference, as I said, is very small.

Answer (score 8):

I had a test yesterday, use [] vs iterator, the code is create a vector with some elements and remove some elements from the vector.
This is the code uses operator [] to access elements

```
  TimeSpent([](){
    std::vector<int> vt = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    for (int i = int(vt.size()) - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      if (vt[i] % 2 == 0)
      {
        //cout << "removing " << vt[i] << endl;
        vt.erase(vt.begin() + i);
      }
    }
  });
```

The following code is about access vector elements by using iterator

```
  TimeSpent([](){
    std::vector<int> vt = { 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 };
    for (std::vector<int>::iterator num = vt.begin(); num != vt.end();)
    {
      if (*num % 2 == 0)
      {
        num = vt.erase(num);
      }
      else
      {
        ++num;
      }
    }
  });
```

Tested by calling them by this function separately

```
void TimeSpent(std::function<void()> func)
{
  const int ONE_MIL = 10000;
  long times = ONE_MIL;
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point start = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  while (times > 0)
  {
    func();
    --times;
  }
  std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point end = std::chrono::steady_clock::now();
  cout << "time elapsed : " << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - start).count() << endl;
}
```

Tested environment is visual studio 2013 pro. version 4.5.51650
The results are :
operator[] : 192 
iterator   : 212 
Summary: when we access the vector container, operator [] is faster than iterator.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that vector iterators are implemented as pointers internally (in a good STL implementation), so in general there should be negligible performance difference between the two idioms. But if you want to know how these perform on *your* platform, why don't you measure it with a little test program? I don't think it would take more than 5 minutes to measure execution time of e.g. 1 million iterations with both variants...

Answer (score 1):

As always, it depends. Normally I wouldn't think you'd see any kind of difference, but only you can determine that by profiling your code. Some compilers implement vector iterators as raw pointers, and some don't. Also, in debug builds, some compilers may be using a checked iterator, which may be slower. But in production mode it may not be any different. Profile it and see.

Answer (score 1):

With optimization (-O2) the timings should improve (should be nearly identical).

Answer (score 0):

In terms of speed, I think might be *almost* same.
Better, you can profile and check anyway.

At least you can reduce the number of variables used :)

```
for( i = 0; i < size ; i++){
    // some operations on v items
    v[i];
    v[size-i+1];
}
```

About `const_iterator`: Pls refer my Q: A[re const_iterators faster ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/755347/are-const-iterators-faster)

Comment: are you sure that "size - i + 1" for every loop is faster than just a "j--" or better a "--j" ?
i think no, so i prefer to have more variables and less clock cicles :P

Comment: I guess these are micro optimizations and as people say, micro optimizations are evil!

Comment: @Simone: I think that is a premature optimization. A compiler could very well be generating optimal code for aJ's example. Again, if you don't profile you won't know.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go for iterators, but what I would optimize is calling `end()` in the loop and would change preincrement to postincrement. I.e. I'd

```
std::vector<SomeClass *> v;
std::vector<SomeClass *>::iterator i,ie;
std::vector<SomeClass *>::reverse_iterator j,je;

// i loops forward, j loops backward
for( i=v.begin(),ie=v.end(), j=v.rbegin(),je=v.rend(); i!=ie && j!=je; ++i,++j ){
    // some operations on v items
}
```

And I don't think it's premature microoptimization, it's just writing better code. Much less evil than calling every attempt to write efficient code premature microoptimization and substituting thinking with profiling.

Comment: And why not removing `j!=je` in the test, as the two conditions are identical?

Comment: rafak, the conditions aren't identical, even though they should coincide. I just preserved original logic, which is somewhat valid - there's nothing wrong with being on the safe side. I'm unlikely to keep both conditions, though, in my code.

Answer (score 0):

I was confused about something similar and wrote a program to test the performance : https://github.com/rajatkhanduja/Benchmarks/blob/master/C%2B%2B/vectorVsArray.cpp

Here's the relevant observations for reading/writing to vector<int> of size 1m using g++ (without any optimization flags), on Linux-i686 (64-bit machine) with 7.7 GB RAM:-

Time taken to write to vector using indices. : 11.3909 ms

Time taken to read from vector using indices, sequentially. : 4.09106 ms

Time taken to read from vector using indices, randomly. : 39 ms

Time taken to write to vector using iterators (sequentially). : 24.9949 ms

Time taken to read from vector using iterators (sequentially). : 18.8049 ms

Comment: What are you compiler flags? `for (int i = 0; i < ARR_SIZE; i++) { tmp = v[i]; }` can easily be optimized to a single statement by any intelligent compiler. In fact, most compilers will notice that **you don't even read the variable anywhere**. The fact that that code still takes 4 ms suggests that you may be compiling with optimizations completely disabled, which would make your benchmarks very misleading.

Answer (score -2):

You are not only prematurely optimizing, you are micro-optimizing.  This is an evil almost as bad as the former (the difference being that very, very, very rarely it is actually necessary to micro-optimize).  Put the two together and you've got a recipe for disaster.

If you run a profiler and find this area of code is a bottleneck then you will need to optimize.  You don't optimize by trying to reduce your loop from taking 23 clock cycles to 22.  You optimize by finding ways to reduce the O() of your algorithm.  But until you run a profiler you should be paying more attention to design than any other concern.