# starting index and ending index of elements in a array(vector) that are greater than a value

Tags: c++, intel-ipp

Given a array like this:

```
{1, 3, 11, 2, 24, 13, 5....}
```

The array length might be larger than 1,000.

If the value of the element is inappropriate, such as larger than 10, it shall be replaced by appropriate value. In this case, the appropriate value is calculated by linear interpolation.

For example:

> Arr = {1, 3, 11, 2, 24, 13, 5....};

The new array shall be:

> NewArr = {1, 3, 3+(2-3)/2, 2, 2+(5-2)/3, 2+2*(5-2)/3, 5, ...}

In order to do this, I have to know **the starting and ending index** of the inappropriate elements.

> The starting and ending index shall be (2,2) indicating the "11" and (4,5) indicating the "24, 13"

I have tried the `for loop`. But it is not efficient. 
Then I searched `IPP API` and did not get an result. :(

Is there a better idea?

Thanks for your help, :).

**BTW**: `IPP API` will be a better choice.

Update:

Sample Codes:

```
int arr[] = {1, 3, 11, 2, 24, 13, 5....};

/// find the starting index and ending index of inappropriate values
/// (2,2) (4,5).
int i = 0; 
std::map<int,int> Segments;
if(arr[i] > Threshold)
{
    int b = i;
    while(arr[i] > Threshold )
        i ++;
    int e = i;
    Segments.insert(std::map<int,int>::value_type(b,e));
}

/// linear interpolation
for(std::map<int,int>::iterator i = 0; i != Segments.end(); i ++) /// len means the number of inappropriate segments  
{
    //// linear interpolation of each segments
    int b = i->first;
    int e = i->second;
    int num = e - b + 1;
    float step = (arr[e+1]-arr[b-1]) / num; // For short. The case that b=0 or e=len-1 is not considered. 
    for(int j = b; j <= e; j ++)
        arr[j] = arr[j-1] + step;
}
```

**Update2**:
 Thanks for all your help. But based of the answers of these questions:[Speed accessing a std::vector by iterator vs by operator[]/index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524233/speed-accessing-a-stdvector-by-iterator-vs-by-operator-index) and [Why use iterators instead of array indices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices), the efficients of two forms( for vs iterator) are almost the same. So `iterator` might not be good enough.

I usually used the `SIMD` such as `IPP API` as the optimize option. But I did not figure it out since all the `find` API only get **the first occurrence** of the specified element.

I will update the solution if I figure out some day. :)

Comment: HOw about showing us some of your code?

Comment: Have you tried to simply use e.g. [`std::replace_if`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/replace) to replace the wrong values? While "larger than 1000" can mean anything from 1001 to infinity, iterating over a couple of thousands entries in an array on a modern computer is really fast.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg, I have to calculate the new value by linear interpolation. I am afraid the `std::replace_if` wont work.

Comment: @Steve - Then look at the std::transform algorithm function that I gave as an answer.  The functor is going to be a little more complex, but it should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to search for a particular value, and replace the items from a vector that match a certain criteria, then that can be done in one line using transform().

The replace_if() can also be used, but given the vague description of your issue, I don't know if the replacement value needs to vary depending on the original value (replace_if needs a constant replacement value).  So let's go with std::transform() for now.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

struct Transformer 
{
   bool ThisNumberNeedsTransformation(int num) { 
     // you fill this in.  Return true if number needs to be changed, false otherwise
   }

   int TransformNumber(int num) {
      // you fill this in.  Return the changed number, given the original number.
   }

   int operator()(int num)
   {
      if ( ThisNumberNeedsTransformation(num) )
          return TransformNumber(num);
      return num;
   }
};

int main()
{
     std::vector<int> intVector;
     //...
     std::transform(intVector.begin(), intVector.end(), intVector.begin(), Transformer());
}
```

Basically, the struct serves as a function object.  For each of the items in the intVector, the function object will operate on that number.  If the number matches the criteria, then the number is transformed and returned, else the original number is returned.

Since you didn't really clarify what your criteria is to change numbers, this approach gives the solution to your issue more flexibility.  All you need to do is fill in the two functions that I left open in the `Transformer` struct, then things should work correctly.

If your needs are more complex, the function object Transformer can be expanded upon to include member variables, or just simply put, can be as complex as you want to make it.

Also remember, if you're timing these things, *time a release, optimized build*.  Don't time "debug" or unoptimized builds.

Comment: WOW. Thanks for your answer. But I am afraid I have to calculate the new value by linear interpolation. This means I have to get two appropriate values which is next to the inappropriate values. BTW, the `release` and `full optimized` is really a good method.

Comment: @Steve - I edited my answer.  Basically what you just stated is exactly the reason why function objects are used -- the complexity of your requirements can be coded right into the struct.  If you need to "remember" values, then you can add member variables that keep track of these values.

Comment: But based of the answers of these questions:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524233/speed-accessing-a-stdvector-by-iterator-vs-by-operator-index and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/131241/why-use-iterators-instead-of-array-indices, the efficients of two forms( for vs iterator) are almost the same. I am afraid that `iterator` might not be good enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what you mean by the "starting and ending index of the inappropriate elements", so I'm going to assume you just mean *the index*.

Using a vector here would be a good approach:

```
std::vector<int> the_stuff {1, 3, 11, 2, 24, 13, 5, ... };
std::vector<int>::iterator it = the_stuff.begin();

while (it != the_stuff.end()
{
   if (*it > 10) { // do stuff };
   etc.
}
```

You get the idea. Use a [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), and it should make things a lot easier for you. search / insert / get indexes / remove / etc. at your leisure.

Answer (score 0):

If you store your number in an std::vector, you can iterate over the array through an iterator. As soon as you find an element that meets your condition and needs to be removed, you can remove it and at the same time assign your iterator to the next element. This will be the most efficient way:

Here is what your code will look like:

```
std::vector<int> intVector;
for(auto it = intVector.begin(); it != intVector.end(); ++it)
{
    if (*it > 10)
    {
        it = intVector.erase(it);
    }
}
```