# Whats the point of .begin() and .end()?

Tags: c++, arrays, std, stdarray

In C++ library arrays, what are some cases where it's useful to have the `.begin()` and `.end()` member functions?

On cplusplus.com, the example use is to iterate through an array:

```
for ( auto it = myarray.begin(); it != myarray.end(); ++it )
```

But

```
for (int i = 0; i < myarray.size(); i++)
```

can be used for that.

Comment: `begin()` and `end()` work for *every* STL container.

Comment: without it you wouldn't be able to use it in a ranged based for loop.

Comment: If you use plain arrays, stick to plain indexes or pointers. But as soon as you use the containers from C++ standard library, you should use the iterators to use a common syntax through all containers.

Comment: std::begin and std::end work for std::array

Comment: Not to mention `end()` is often used as a "not found" value by many standard algorithmic  functions.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

`begin()` and `end()` return iterators. Iterators provide uniform syntax to access different types of containers. At the first glance they might look like an overkill for traversing a simple array, but consider that you could write the same code to traverse a list, or a map.

This uniform access to various containers will allow you to write algorithms that work on all of them without knowing their internal structure. A for loop from begin to end is just a first piece in a much larger mosaic. Just look up the list of [standard algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to appreciate the power of this simple abstraction.

Answer (score 10):

The whole point of standard containers is the ability to change them and use the same syntax. If you had a linked list, the first syntax still works.

Also it is equivalent to a pointer. i is an index so myarray[i] is slightly slower than it.

Comment: ... and, more importantly, having the same syntax for iteration over the container means you can write a template that will work for any of them.

Comment: Most who care point to negligible difference. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524233/speed-accessing-a-stdvector-by-iterator-vs-by-operator-index

Answer (score 7):

In addition to be generic with other containers, `begin`, `end` is useful for *for range*

```
for (const auto& e : myarray)
```

Answer (score 0):

Now try iterating through a linked list. The only efficient way is to iterate from one item to the next, until you reach the end.