# What is the best pattern to return dynamically allocated buffer from a function in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, memory-management, unique-ptr

I'm in the process of refactoring some old code. There's a C style function that works like this: (Obviously I've simplified it here)

```
int LoadData(char** buf1, int* buf1Len, char** buf2, int* buf2Len) {
    *buf1Len = DetermineLength1();
    *buf1 = (char*)malloc(*buf1Len);
    // Fill buf1
    *buf2Len = DetermineLength2();
    *buf2 = (char*)malloc(*buf2Len);
    // Fill buf2
    int result = 0; // Or some other INT depending of result
    return result;
}
```

Now, I'd like to update this code to somehow return a unique_ptr or equivalent, so the pointer will be automatically managed by the caller, and the caller won't ever forget to free the memory.

I couldn't find a good solution, so currently I've changed the code to the following:

```
int LoadData(std::unique_ptr<char[]>* ubuf1, int* buf1Len, std::unique_ptr<char[]>* ubuf2, int* buf2Len) {
    // same code as above, and finally:
    ubuf1->reset(buf1);
    ubuf2->reset(buf2);
    return result;
}
```

This doesn't look good, so I'm looking to see if there's a better solution. Since I'm returning two buffers, using the `unique_ptr` as the return value is not an option.

Is there any better way for this?

Comment: Any reason you can't use `std::vector<char>` for `buf1` and `buf2`?  Pass by reference to `LoadData` which can then simply call `resize` accordingly.

Answer (score 11):

Don't use `std::unique_ptr` for arrays if you don't have to. The proper tool for storing dynamic arrays is usually `std::vector`. It packs the size information right along with the object, where it belongs. If your `char*` are being used as strings, then you might want to use `std::string` instead.

```
std::pair<std::vector<char>, std::vector<char>>
LoadData()
{
    std::vector<char> buf1(DetermineLength1());
    // Fill buf1

    std::vector<char> buf2(DetermineLength2());
    // Fill buf2

    return { std::move(buf1), std::move(buf2) };
}
```

If you still need your `int` return result, then you can change the function to return `std::tuple<int, std::vector<char>, std::vector<char>>`. Or better yet, create a struct with meaningful names for the members.

Comment: Why you say "Don't use std::unique_ptr for arrays if you don't have to."? Any reason to not use unique_ptr here?

Comment: @Nabi: The size of an array is an intrinsic property of the array. Using a unique_ptr requires you to store the size separately. This is error prone. What advantages do you think a unique_ptr offers over a vector?

Comment: @Benjamin_lindley: Yes you right, but using a vector to store a char array buffer needs more memory and its accessibility has less speed from char * or unique_ptr or std::string. I'm convinced the best solution for char array buffer is using std::string and its data() function, but i don't like its name (string) when its data will be some binary bytes.

Comment: @Nabi I'm not so sure that vector will be slower. See this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2524233/speed-accessing-a-stdvector-by-iterator-vs-by-operator-index
> The performance difference is likely negligable or none (the compiler might optimise them to be identical);

Comment: @LiranFunaro: No, that link is not related to this comparation. In some cases char array is very faster to use, like bulk copying.

Comment: @ BenjaminLindley and @LiranFunaro, Yes, you right! now I think the best solution is using vector and its performance would be same as char *. Thanks!